# Iterate over rows in a data frame to search by regular expressions

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I am trying to fetch sql tables from query using regular expressions. That is done for single query by using `re.findall`

```
import re
Query = ["SELECT * FROM   WS_DE_Staging.stage_dual_h_20"]
for xx in Query:
    r1 = re.findall(r"FROM|JOIN|from|join\s+([A-Za-z_.\[\]]+)",xx)
    print(r1)
```

But now in phase 2 I have to use this for a table in which I hold all the report names and their sql queries. So I am using pandas to read the CSV and create a data frame.

Don't know the next step how I can iterate over all the occurrences using the above `re.findall` expression.

```
import re
Query = ["SELECT * FROM   WS_JE_Staging.stage_dual_h_20", "Select * from DummyEmployee"]
for xx in Query:
    r1 = re.findall(r"FROM|JOIN|from|join\s+([A-Za-z_.\[\]]+)",xx)
    print(r1)

import pandas as pd, re, numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("SqlQ.csv", delimiter=',')

print(df.index)
```

Comment: why would you iterate over the rows? use `str.contains`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex pattern can be simplified using `re.IGNORECASE`. Extracting table names from DF is better than iterating items.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
pattern = r"(?<=from|join)\s+([\da-z_.\[\]]+)"
df = pd.read_csv(r"d:\temp\SqlQ.csv", delimiter=',')
df['table'] = df['sql'].str.extract(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(df)
```

Get unique table list with `Set()`.

```py
df['table'] = df['sql'].str.findall(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df['table'] = df['table'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

Comment: df['table'] = df['CommandText'].str.findall(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

I have replace this statement to include all the tables either after From Or after Join.
But i have some repeating tables. How i can get all the Unique tables from it.

Comment: Get unique table list with Set(). I have updated the reply.

Comment: Thanks mate for your instant help.!!! Cheers..!!!!